# How to add a directory to a certain branch (not master branch) via git

Tags: git, directory, branch, addition

I'm pretty new to using the git tool. So, I would like to add a directory to my github repo. But there were lots of files, so I realized that I had to use git to adding my directory to the repo.
But the problem is that my directory went to the master branch. I must adjust that to go to the **main branch**. How can I choose a specific branch while adding the directory to the github repo? I looked at many similar topics and tried some code but it didn't solve my problem.

By the way, I faced **(master)** word while I was typing in git to add my files to github repo.

Answer (score 0):

To commit to a specific branch you will have to checkout this branch in the first place. `git checkout branchname` does the trick here on the command line. Then you make your changes in code or on your filesystem, do `git add .` to stage all changes, `git commit -m "commit message"`, then you can `git push` to the branch you checked out before.

If you are fine with your changes being on master you may just `git checkout main` to switch over to the branch to be corrected and `git merge master` to apply the changes made to master to also be available on main. Note: this will apply all changes, even those made after you created that directory, to main. If this is okay to you or there are no more changes, go ahead.

If you need the changes on master undone you will need to dig a bit deeper: `git checkout master` first to be on the correct branch. Do `git log` then to figure out the hash of the commit on master *before* the one adding that folder. `git reset --hard hashOfThatCommit`, then `git push origin master --force` to make the changes available to your server. Note: This is only an option if you are okay with losing **all** changes made to master since the commit before adding that folder. After that `git checkout main`, make your changes there and follow the beginning of my answer to commit them to history.

You may seriously consider reading up on git in the official documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/doc) and maybe get a git gui tool like Gitkraken or fork. Those, as much as their use is controversial in difficult situations, visually provide your repo information and history for an easier overview than the command line if you are not used to that.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried 'git checkout branchname' , and saw different things on the git bash screen. So I stuck at this place. Before that, I entered some git code, like you said (git add, git commit) and I got some results. But it didn't solve my problem.

As a newbie, I faced really weird problems using git. So, I just applied a different method to solve (not a super solution, using github with the basic command). I realized that I should need to learn the foundation of git. So I turned this way to enhances my skills. Thank you again.